# Linq - into leftjoin

Tags: c#, linq

```
from foo in context.Foo
join current in context.v_CurrentFooIds on foo.Id equals
   current.CurrentId
join approved in context.v_ApprovedFooIds on foo.VersionIndependentId
   equals approved.VersionIndependentId into leftjoin
from appr in leftjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
   matches.Contains(foo.UniqueFormulaNumber) && !foo.IsTemplate
   && appr == null
```

I don't understand what into leftjoin does in this context.

I'm lost at `equals approved.VersionIndependent into leftJoin from appr in leftjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

What does this mean?

Comment: `leftjoin` is the intermediate result obtained from joining those three collections above. You could name it whatever you want, the words `leftjoin` have no special significance here. You could have called it, for example, `theResultThatIGotFromDoingThatLastLeftJoin`.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thank  you Asad for the explanation. That leftjoin really threw me off.